# What is a good way to call a function when two separate Ajax calls complete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I have some JS similar to the following simplified version:

```
var MyAjax = $.ajax({
    url: 'api/myApi',
    type: "POST",
    data: myData,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        if (condition) {
            var weightCounts = $.ajax({
                url: 'api/myApi',
                type: "POST",
                data: myConditionalData,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (conditionalData) {
                    MyExternalMethod(data, conditionalData)
    }
});
```

Basically I have two Ajax calls. I have one that retrieves some data, and a second that retrieves some data if an additional setting is enabled. The reason the conditional call is nested in the success event of the main call is because the args for `MyExternalMethod()` are generated by these calls and so they both need to complete.

Conceptually though, these calls are totally independent of one another, and the conditional call does not need to wait for the success event of the initial call, that was just the best method I could think of at the time of writing this code. I would like to refactor this to fix the slowness of waiting on the first request to execute the conditional, but I am not sure of the best method.

My best idea so far is something like:

```
var firstData = null;
var secondData = null;

var MyFirstAjax = $.ajax({
    url: 'api/myApi',
    type: "POST",
    data: myData,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        firstData = data;
        if (secondData){
            MyExternalMethod(firstData, secondData)
        }

});

var MySecondAjax = $.ajax({
    url: 'api/myApi',
    type: "POST",
    data: myData,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        secondData = data;
        if (firstData){
            MyExternalMethod(firstData, secondData)
        }
});
```

Is there a standard way other than using these variables as flags? I'm used to kind of flying by the seat of my pants as far as JS works, but I'm trying to write cleaner, more standards-oriented code so I'm wondering if there is a more advantageous way than the above (or does the above have any major drawbacks that I'm not seeing).

Thanks

Comment: I think you want to use http://api.jquery.com/promise/

Comment: This looks interesting too: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/ Sorry, I haven't used these, I just know of them. Just trying to point you in a direction, wish I could help more. This one actually has an example of exactly what you are asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`$.when()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)...

```
var MyFirstAjax = $.ajax({
    url: 'api/myApi',
    type: "POST",
    data: myData,
    dataType: "json"
});

var MySecondAjax = $.ajax({
    url: 'api/myApi',
    type: "POST",
    data: myData,
    dataType: "json"
});

$.when(MyFirstAjax, MySecondAjax).then(function (firstResult, secondResult) {
    var firstData = firstResult[0];
    var secondData = secondResult[0];
    MyExternalMethod(firstData, secondData)
});
```

Comment: Can't believe I didn't know about this before. This is great. I always just set my own booleans up in the complete statements. This is way more elegant. I am assuming this would work with the other statements like $.post and $.get?

Comment: Yes, I believe it will. It works with anything that is a promise. One caveat is that if one of the promises is rejected, the entire thing is rejected (fails). There's more work to be done to get around it if you don't want that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Libraries like `async.js` would help.

Long answer: There are a few way to handle this.

Basically both ajax needs to trigger the same callback say `function check_ajax()` on `success:`, which checks if `firstData` AND `firstData` is available. If so, call `MyExternalMethod`.

A good reference: http://book.mixu.net/node/ch7.html